# Monitor Multiple Airflow instances

Tags: python, airflow, prometheus, grafana

I currently have task a task to monitor completely independent airflow instances running across multiple customer servers. All of them have similar DAGs. I have to combine metrics from all these instances and monitor them. Can anyone please suggest a approach for it?

I tried to use prometheus with multiple statsd exporter and grafana dashboards but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is using tags to differentiate between the metrics of the different instances, but unfortunately, Airflow doesn't push tags for prometheus, it does only for datadog and it will do soon (starting from [2.6.0](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/29093)) for InfluxDB.

If you can use one of these services, you can use the same [stats-prefix](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#statsd-prefix), and add [statsd-tags](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#statsd-datadog-tags) to separate between the different airflow instances:

```
# instance 1:
statsd-datadog-tags=instance:1
# instance 2:
statsd-datadog-tags=instance:2
```

Then you will be able to put the metrics on the same monitor/dashboard, and group and filter them by `instance` name.

Also, in [2.6.0](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28961) we will support removing the variables from the metrics names and sending them as tags, so you will be able to create one dashboard for all your dags/tasks and group by tags to better monitor them.